# Does the @objc marker change the behavior of dynamic variables?

Tags: swift

When declaring a variable as dynamic:

```
dynamic var myProperty: Bool = true
```

is there any advantage or change in behavior by also adding the @objc marker?

```
@objc dynamic var myProperty: Bool = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 4, `dynamic` variables will give a compilation error if they do not have the `@objc` attribute on them. So, you could say the ability to compile is an advantage of adding `@objc`.

Comment: Ok good to know. The project I’m working on is using Swift 3 and wasn’t noticing any difference. For Swift Versions < 4 is adding @objc completely superfluous (minus an upgrade to Swift 4 if and when it's desired)?

Comment: @J2K It seems to. The ObjectiveC runtime is the only one available to Swift, so the only way to achieve `dynamic` behavior is to also be `@objc`. `dynamic` implies `@objc`, but Swift 4 just makes this explicit.

Comment: @J2K At some point, probably not too long from now, Apple will drop support for compiling Swift 3 in Xcode, because Apple. So you should be thinking about converting your code to Swift 4. Having `@objc` there does not cause any harm in Swift 3, and it makes your life easier when it comes time to update your code. So I would not call it superfluous at all.

Answer (score 0):

See Apple's documentation itself. It states

> Declarations marked with the dynamic modifier must also be explicitly   marked with the @objc attribute unless the @objc attribute is implicitly added by the declaration’s context. For information about when the @objc attribute is implicitly added. See [Declaration Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH35-ID348)